# Why does position:absolute reset top and left coordinates?

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/PoQMjmj

```
<div>
  <div class="card">Text</div>
<div class="card">Text2</div>
</div>

div.card
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:pink;
  transition:all 0.7s;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Both of the child divs are block level elements, but when I set position:absolute to both of them without giving any values for top and left properties, both divs get stacked together in the same position.

Is this part of the CSS specs?

Comment: Because absolute position remove item from normal flow. From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) : _It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block_

Comment: @Sfili_81 - In this case, it's neither. Having no inset values, both elements are placed at their static position. But they take up no space in that normal flow.

Comment: So both element automatically positioning on top:0; left:0;

Comment: @Sfili_81 - No, that's the point. They are positioned at `top:auto; left:auto`. Auto in this case will result in used values of `top:8px; left:8px` because of the default body margin.

Comment: @Alohci yes you are right. :)